# C++ vector erase method delete my object

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, abstract-class, erase

I first get an object A from the vector, then I call the erase method to destroy that object in my vector because I don't need it anymore. However, from the debugger, I found that the object A I got before calling erase method is also destroyed. I don't understand that because I thought that what I got is a copy of that object and erase method should have nothing to do with my object A.

Code

Class Unit

Header file

```
#ifndef UNIT_H
#define UNIT_H
#include <iostream>

class Unit
{
protected:
    int id;

public:
    Unit::Unit(int num = -1);
    virtual ~Unit() = default;
    virtual int getID();

};

#endif
```

CPP file

```
#include "Unit.h"

Unit::Unit(int num)
{
    id = num;
}

int Unit::getID()
{
    return id;

}
```

Class Box

Header file

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Unit.h"

class Box : public Unit
{
private:
    std::string* type;
    int* val;
public:
    Box::Box();
    ~Box();
    int getVal();
    std::string getName();
    int getID() override;
};

    #endif
```

CPP file

```
#include <time.h>
#include "Box.h"

Box::Box() : Unit(5)
{
    int tmp = rand() % 3;
    if (tmp == 0)
    {
        type = new std::string("hp");  // health cur
        val = new int(rand() % 10 + 1);
    }
    else if (tmp == 1)
    {
        type = new std::string("exp");  // skill level or health max
        val = new int(rand() % 5 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        type = new std::string("punish");  // minus health cur
        val = new int(-1);
    }
}

Box::~Box()
{
    delete type;
    delete val;
}

int Box::getVal()
{
    return *val;
}

std::string Box::getName()
{
    return *type;
}

int Box::getID()
{
    return id;
}
```

main file

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Box test;
    std::vector<Box> bag;
    bag.push_back(test);

    Box tmp = bag[0];

    bag.erase(bag.begin() + 0);

    cout << tmp.getVal();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the screenshot from the debugger and because I don't have 10 reputations, I can't display it directly.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ7uF.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rE4n.png)

As you can see, the "type" and "val" data member of class Box is modified.

Comment: Hard to be sure based on incomplete information, but my first guess would be that you have a copy constructor that's not copying correctly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin. From the debugger, I can see that the copy is correct because object tmp has all the data member correctly. After erasing the element in the vector "bag", everything changed. I don't understand that. Elements in vector "bag" are not pointer.

Comment: `-17891602` translates to `0xFEEEFEEE` in hexadecimal display. That's the value assigned by the debug heap after `HeapFree` was called (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/353606/1889329), for example). That's a strong indication, that the object was indeed purged. With the information provided, there's nothing we can do to diagnose the issue, though. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: 2 lines of code with **no** definitions is not enough.

Comment: Please reopen my question, during the time off, I was editing my question.

Comment: Your assignment/copy constructor is not correct. When you a get the element from the vector you get a copy and when you erase it from the vector the destructor is called invalidating your pointers.

Comment: @MrTux  You mean "Box tmp = bag[0] " ? Why is that

Comment: `type` and `val` is pointer, the generized copy constructor doesn't perform deep copy, `tmp` is copied from `bag[0]`, but `type` and `val` is still pointing to the same thing. When `bag[0]` being destroyed, `type` and `val` in `tmp` become dangled.

Comment: @JerryCoffin was right - obviously. 1. Don't use pointer and raw `new` and `delete`. 2. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @songyuanyao   I see what you mean. So how should I fix this?

Comment: It appears that @JerryCoffin had the best guess with a bad copy constructor. You are copying raw pointers.

Comment: @Pixelchemist   I'm learning pointers and memory management, so what should I do to fix this while keep these pointers?

Comment: @kevinnnluo If you want to perform deep copy, you have to write copy ctor and operator by yourself. See the link Pixelchemist posted form more infomations.

Comment: *"So how should I fix this?"* - Stop using pointers as class members. There is no reason for an `int*` or a `std::string*`. Simply make the objects class members, and you don't have to do anything else (well, you need to remove the d'tor body).

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. Here we have a clear distinction between questions and answers. If you want, you can post an answer to your question. I've rolled back your "add solution" edit.

Comment: @bolov Ok. Sorry about that.

Comment: @kevinnnluo Don't worry about it. You'll learn the ropes as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page about the return type from the index call

```
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at
```

I believe that you may have a reference, not a different object.

Comment: Then how do I get a copy of that object?

Comment: If at this point: `Box tmp = bag[index];` the typename `Box` doesn't involve a reference, then `tmp`isn't a reference.

Comment: Is your "Box tmp = ..." perhaps a Box&?  I'm just guessing because you said it was abstract, so that means it's pretty hard to instantiate one.  If you have a way to show more code as @Pavel suggested, I'll bet that it becomes clear to us.

Comment: What do you mean by the type name doesn't involved a reference?

Comment: @JohnGriffin  What I wanna do is to get a copy from the vector and I just use the operator []. I use a simple example by replacing Box to built-in type int and it didn't show that it is a reference.

Comment: The code is too much to show. Otherwise, I would post it.

Comment: @kevinnnluo: Reduce it until you have the minimal code that still exhibits the problematic behaviour.

Comment: @Pixelchemist is absolutely right that your code (only 2 lines by the way) indicates a type Box and I would assume that it is not abstract as he does, except that you say that it is.  If Box is not a typedef for a reference type, The Box will get a copy.  Check the 'this' pointer of tmp in your debugger against the 'this' pointer in the vector at [index].  And of course, perhaps your assessment of what is happening is unclear.   How about some more Box information for us?